# How can I make column names like "X_re" after recoding?

Tags: r, r-colnames

I recoded columns 'satface1, satface2,..., satface6' and
I want to make new columns in my data name 'satface1_re, satface_2, ..., satface6_re'.
How can I make it?

What I tried was:

```
data$re <- data %>% select((num_range("satface",1:6,width = 1))) %>%
  mutate_all(function(x) recode(x,'1=;2=5;3=4;4=3;5=1;6=1'))
```

Then new columns were made like 're.satface1, re.satface2,..., re.satface6'

Comment: Do you want to rename the columns or create new ones?

Comment: I want to create new ones

Comment: And what do you want to fill the new columns with?

Comment: i want to recode "satface 1" to "satface 6" columns and make them as new columns "satface 1_re" to "satface6_re",

Comment: Hi I've edited the answer. If it answers your question or is helpful plz consider accepting and/or upvoting it.

Answer (score 0):

Sample data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  satface1 = NA,
  satface2 = NA,
  satface3 = NA,
  satface4 = NA
)
```

To create new columns with the suffix `_re`, you can subset `df`and use `paste`:

```
df[paste(names(df), "_re", sep = "")] <- NA
```

Result:

```
df
  satface1 satface2 satface3 satface4 satface1_re satface2_re satface3_re satface4_re
1       NA       NA       NA       NA          NA          NA          NA          NA
```